# Multiple arithmetic operations on single tensor

Tags: pytorch

For a 2D tensor with even and odd numbers, I would like to
do different arithmetic operation depending on if the number
in the tensor is even or odd.  I've created the tensor and created
a corresponding true false (even or odd) tensor, but am not sure how to proceed.

```
import torch

list1 = [
[10, 25, 75, 10, 50],
[25, 30, 35, 40, 30],
[45, 50, 55, 60, 20],
[50, 20, 15, 20, 10],
[10, 25, 40, 50, 35]]

tensor2 = torch.tensor(list1)
tensor3=tensor2 % 2
print(tensor3)
print(torch.eq(tensor3, 0)) #even numbers
print(torch.eq(tensor3, 1)) #odd numbers
#do 3x+1 for odd numbers, ie the tensor where indexes are false for even
#do x/2 for even numbers, ie the tensor where indexes are true for even
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [torch.where](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html)

In your case the code would be:

```
list1 = [
[10, 25, 75, 10, 50],
[25, 30, 35, 40, 30],
[45, 50, 55, 60, 20],
[50, 20, 15, 20, 10],
[10, 25, 40, 50, 35]]

tensor2 = torch.tensor(list1, type = torch.float64)
res = torch.where(tensor2 % 2 == 0, tensor2 / 2, tensor2 * 3 + 1)

>>> res
tensor([[  5.,  76., 226.,   5.,  25.],
        [ 76.,  15., 106.,  20.,  15.],
        [136.,  25., 166.,  30.,  10.],
        [ 25.,  10.,  46.,  10.,   5.],
        [  5.,  76.,  20.,  25., 106.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```